# problem to run ionic app in browser via localhost its error

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

[image: 1]

```
  The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

PS C:\Users\61475\Desktop\Interactive App Development\contact> ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] Error: Unknown arguments: host, port

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

i want to try run on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the root directory

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Then try

```
ionic serve
```